# YAML response from Flask MySQL query doesn't seem formatted correctly

Tags: python, mysql, flask, yaml, pyyaml

I'm trying to return a yaml response in my python flask app, but what I get instead is the dictionary object wrapped in yaml.

```
# Open connection to db
con = mdb.connect('localhost','root','root','transport')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.execute("""
        SELECT stop_id,arrival_time
        FROM trips t
    """)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return yaml.dump(rows)
```

According to PyYAML documentation I've expected my output to look something like this (Or some other transformation of my python dict to a YAML format).

```
- 
  - arrival_time: '09:53:57'
  - stop_id: '13326'
- 
  - arrival_time: '09:53:58'
  - stop_id: '13515'
```

But instead the output I'm getting is this -

```
- {arrival_time: '09:53:57', stop_id: '13326'}
- {arrival_time: '09:53:58', stop_id: '13515'}
```

How can I properly format the response I get from MySQL to YAML?